# JSONP URL shorner

Tags: url, jsonp

I tried a few, but didn't find any capable of handling very long URLs (about 2-3kb). Is there any URL shortener that can handle very long URLs and can be used in JSONP (or some other pure client side way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's goo.gl URL shortening has a rest API, which accepts cross domain requests. It will require to create an API key, though. It can then be used like this

```
$.ajax("https://content.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=YOUR_KEY&alt=json",
{
  type: 'POST',      
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({        
    "longUrl": "http://something"
  })
}).done(function(data){
  var shortUrl = data.id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Making your own. How you make your own is you get a domain, then you use PHP and MySQLi to add the URLs to your database, so when you go to a path such as 
example.com/myurli
then it goes to myurliofthebigestdomainintheworld.com